# Command-line email client for gzipped Maildir

Tags: freebsd, email, mutt

I'm looking for a way to manage email from the files in the user Maildir folder (no IMAP or POP3 involved). I've used [Mutt](http://www.mutt.org) with some satisfaction, but it only works with files that have not yet been compressed with `gzip` (this is done automatically, to save storage space).
I tried adding `open-hook Z$ "gzip -cd %f > %t"` to `.muttrc` but `mutt` doesn't seem able to handle them.

Is there a way to make `mutt` handle Maildir format mailboxes where (some) **messages are gzipped**? How?

Is there maybe a better approach to **reading email from the command line**? I can be content with just browsing and searching (no sending), but there has to be a better way than `zgrep` and `zcat` alone.

Here's a sample list of files from my INBOX, those ending with `Z` have already been compressed:

```
1494921455.M438425P32704V0000005CI002B4BB2_0.my.server.com,S=34928:2,Sb,Z
1501135580.M700848P59781V0000005CI002A90B3_0.my.server.com,S=5693:2,Sb,Z
1501692943.M145468P66218V0000005CI002C99C6_0.my.server.com,S=5071:2,Sbe,Z
1504108468.M406192P97792V0000005CI002B2A6C_0.my.server.com,S=3168:2,RS,Z
1504165498.M905738P22709V0000005CI002B747E_0.my.server.com,S=6777:2,Sbe,Z
1507018689.M186684P83403V0000005CI002AA105_0.my.server.com,S=1568:2,Sbe
1507643724.M161408P53438V0000005CI002ABF60_0.my.server.com,S=81072:2,Sb
1507709862.M455420P49529V0000005CI002AB13B_0.my.server.com,S=1629:2,Sbe
1507762300.M749739P55548V0000005CI002A7751_0.my.server.com,S=21286:2,S
1507762301.M197475P55553V0000005CI002A7766_0.my.server.com,S=21285:2,S
```

Comment: Switching to the mbox format is no good solution for you? Mutt handles compressed mbox files (any compression tool, it's configurable).

Comment: @Kusalananda Unfortunately, I can't change how the server manages the email messages (Maildir format, individually gzipped). I genuinely thought Mutt would be able to run the hook command on each message.